# Move Customer from one website to another

Tags: magento2, customer

I am able to move the customer from one website to another from the list view.
However, I am not able to change the associated website after clicking edit
Also, after moving customer from one website to another, the customer is not receiving any email.

Is it a Magento Bug? or there is solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

there is a setting in `Shops –> Configuration –> Customer –> Customer configuration` where you can define if user accounts are shared globally in Magento or just per Website.

If you set it to "per website" the website the user registered on is stored in the database.

If you want to move the user from one website to another, you can export the customer, change the associated website and store and reimport the customer.

EDIT: Maybe the best answer, tested it in my shop and is much faster than the export&import and does a direct database manipulation from the Magento Admin:

1. Open the customer you want to change in the customer administration.
2. Right click on the grey "assigned website" field and select to "inspect element" (may be labeled different in your browser).
3. Find the html source code which may look like:

> ```
> <select class="admin__control-select" data-bind="
>     attr: {
>         name: inputName,
>         id: uid,
>         disabled: disabled,
>         'aria-describedby': noticeId
>     },
>     hasFocus: focused,
>     optgroup: options,
>     value: value,
>     optionsCaption: caption,
>     optionsValue: 'value',
>     optionsText: 'label'" name="customer[website_id]" id="FJRUS8S" disabled="true" aria-describedby="notice-FJRUS8S">
> ```

4. Delete `disabled="true"`
5. Change the website to the desired one
6. Change "send welcome email from" to the store view inside the target website
7. Save the customer.

This customer can now log in the new website and all of the order history etc. is available in the new website.